# Transformar uma pesquisa em um campo que disque ao clicar no celular

Tags: php, html

Estou desenvolvendo um site com cadastro de empresas locais em PHP e MySQL com nome, endereço e telefone, até ai tudo bem, estou travado no item onde quando fazem uma pesquisa no site o resultado que retornar na tabela, onde tem o número de telefone e celular gostaria de transformar em um link para que possa ser clicado e o mesmo ir para o discador do celular...
tipo, se for um numero fixo na página sei que se colocar:

```
<a href="tel:12345678">12345678</a>
```

Ele se transforma de modo que posso clicar e ele vai para o discador do celular, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso com os números que aparecem na consulta:

```
<?php foreach($clientes as $cliente):?>
                    <tr>
                  <td><?=$cliente->nome?> </br>
                      <?=$cliente->endereco?></td>
                  <td><?=$cliente->telefone?>  
                      <?=$cliente->celular?></td>
              </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </table>
```

Os campos "telefone?" e "celular?" são os que preciso transformar em link para discar... Só não sei como montar o codigo com `<a href=tel>`.

Comment: Acredito que isso dependa da implementação do navegador, alguns aplicativos de smartphones podem fazer isso, como o Gmail de celular, não é em todo local que vai funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Você pode incluir os dados dentro da tag `<a>`, montando desta forma:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($clientes as $cliente):?>
    <tr>
       <td><?=$cliente->nome?> </br>
          <?=$cliente->endereco?></td>
       <td><a href="tel:<?=$cliente->telefone?>"><?=$cliente->telefone?></a>
          <a href="tel:<?=$cliente->celular?>"><?=$cliente->celular?></a></td>
       </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

**[Demo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/txVxzg)**

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo, fazia dias que tava travado nesse bendito código...
Valeu mesmo!!!